# Laravel :: Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Product::getTax(), 0 passed

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code:

```
public function taxesData(Product $product)
{
    $taxes = \Auth::user()->taxes;
    foreach ($taxes as $tax) {
        echo "$product->getTax($tax)";
    }
}
```

which on testing gives this error:

> Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Product::getTax(), 0 passed in E:\projects\ims\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes.php on line 411 and exactly 1 expected

However, just a small change makes it works, but I am not able to understand. Why?

```
public function taxesData(Product $product)
{
    $taxes = \Auth::user()->taxes;
    foreach ($taxes as $tax) {
        echo $product->getTax($tax);
    }
}
```

Please help.

I tried to simplify it for the purpose of posting here... actually i am creating json with html component for a datatable ->

```
public function taxesData(Product $product)
{
    $taxes = \Auth::user()->taxes;
            return datatables()
        ->of($taxes)
        ->addColumn('check',function($tax) use($product){
            if($product->hasTax($tax)){
                return "<input type='checkbox' class='input-sm row-checkbox' name='tax[$tax->id]' value='$tax->id' checked>";
            }else{
                return "<input type='checkbox' class='input-sm row-checkbox' name='tax[$tax->id]' value='$tax->id'>";
            }
        })
        ->editColumn('tax', function($tax) use($product){
            return "<span class='currencyinput form-control'>
                    <input id='rate' type='text' name='rate' value='$product->getTax($tax)' required autofocus>
                    </span>"
        })
        ->toJson();
}
```

Adding getTax method

```
public function getTax(Tax $t)
{
    if($this->hasTax($t)){
        return  $this->taxes->find($t->id)->pivot->tax;
    }
    else{
        return $t->pivot->tax;
    }
}


public function hasTax(Tax $tax)
{
    foreach ($this->taxes as $t) {
        if($t->id == $tax->id){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why do you enclose function call in quotes?

Comment: I was actually doing this when i got the error,
                return "<span class='currencyinput form-control'>
                        <input id='rate' type='text' name='rate' value='$product->getTax($tax)' required autofocus>
                        </span>";

but then realized that it will still happen if i simply put the call in quotes.

Comment: I understand, i ask __why__ you do this?

Comment: no need of quotes if you enclose in quotes it goes as string.

Comment: I understand, I want the result of my function call to go as string, but the error that I am getting is kind of strange

Comment: If you want your result as string you need to use the correct syntax (see Amarnasan's answer) or use `echo (string) ...`.

Comment: post your model too.

Comment: please share your `getTaxes` function.

Comment: added getTax & hasTax in question

Comment: what version of laravel are you using?

Comment: the problem has something to do with laravel, I'm also trying to replicate it right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I've done so far.

Just for simplicity, I've created a sample Model.

```
// SampleModel.php

public function relatedModels()
{
    return $this->hasMany(RelatedModel::class);
}

// this is like an accessor, but since our model doesn't have
// a property called `relatedModels`, Laravel will ignore it
// until later...
public function getRelatedModels()
{
    return "Sample";
}
```

Given the following code, here are the outputs.

```
$a = SampleModel::find($id);
$a->relatedModels;
// this returns a collection of related models to this model.
$a->getRelatedModels();
// this returns "Sample";

// HOWEVER, when we try to interpolate that member function call.
"$a->getRelatedModels()"
// this throws error that the method `getRelatedModels` must return a relationship.

// I've also tried to add an argument to my existing function to be in-line with your situation.
public function getRelatedModels($a) ...

// this works well
$a->getRelatedModels(1);
// but this, yes, it throws the error as same as what you've got.
"$a->getRelatedModels(1)";
```

The error pointed out this line in the framework's codebase.

```
// HasAttributes.php
protected function getRelationshipFromMethod($method)
{
    $relation = $this->$method(); // <-- this line
```

For some reason, doing `"$a->getRelatedModels(1)"` triggers the `__get` magic method of the model.

Which branches down to this stack call.

```
// Model.php
public function __get($key)
{
    return $this->getAttribute($key);
}
// |
// V
// HasAttributes.php
public function getAttribute($key)
{
    ...
    return $this->getRelationValue($key);
}
// |
// V
// HasAttributes.php
public function getRelationValue($key)
{
    ...
    if (method_exists($this, $key)) {
        return $this->getRelationshipFromMethod($key);
    }
}
// |
// V
// HasAttributes.php
protected function getRelationshipFromMethod($method)
{
    $relation = $this->$method(); // <-- lastly to this
    // $method = "getRelatedModels"
    // since our method `getRelatedModels` needs an argument
    // this call will fail since it wasn't able to provide an argument.
    ...
}
```

That's why you're getting the too few arguments passed exception. I want to investigate further but I have to go home!

I don't know if this is a legit bug for Laravel, but if you do think so, issue it on Laravel's github repository.

**UPDATE**

I've posted an issue in github and this is one of the comments which truly made sense for me.

This is neither a issue with Laravel, nor with PHP. You are just using the wrong syntax, see it here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/23639

Github user *@staudenmeir* commented:

> `"$sampleModel->getRelatedModels()"` is equivalent to `"$sampleModel->getRelatedModels"."()"`.
>
> The usage of variables in strings is limited to `"$foo"` and `"$foo->bar"`. Function calls like `"$foo->bar()"`
>   don't work. You can (but shouldn't) use curly braces for that: `"{$foo->bar()}"`
>
> The better solution is just simple string concatenation:
>
> `"text..." . $sampleModel->getRelatedModels() . "more text..."`

So that is why the magic method `__get` is being called.

Comment: thanks for actually understanding what i am trying to ask... really appreaciate your efforts here...

Comment: np, I was also curious about the issue :)

Comment: I've updated my answer, you might want to take a look.

Answer (score 4):

It fails because you are not following the correct syntax of echo strings.

This would work:

```
echo "{$product->getTax($tax)}";
```

or actually, because you dont' need the quotes for such a simple expression:

```
echo $product->getTax($tax);
```

Comment: I tried to simplify it for the purpose of posting here... i have updated my question with my actual code.